# Method call by passing user instance as a parameter

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to call a method by passing a user instance as a parameter, but I don't know what am I getting wrong, as it is not getting called, but when I pass a single object property it is working fine. I am trying to call the method `getCurrentProfitAndLoss()` from a `try` block.

```
public Double getCurrentProfitAndLoss(){
    Double currentProfitAndLoss = null;
    Userr user = ((OptionsUser)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUserr();
    //user = Userr.findUserr(user.getId());
    HomePageService homePageService = homePageServiceFactory.getObject();
    System.out.println("homePageService object  created" + user.toString());
    try {
        currentProfitAndLoss = homePageService.getCurrentProfitAndLoss(user);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return currentProfitAndLoss;
}
```

This class should be called, but it is not getting called. But when I pass `user.getId()` as a parameter it is working fine.

```
    import com.uforic.optionstrader.domain.Userr;

    @Component(value = "HomePageService")
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    public class HomePageService {
    public Double getCurrentProfitAndLoss(Userr user) {
        System.out.println("iside HOmepageService" + user);
        Double currentProfitPercPA =     StrategyExitReport.findCurrentProfitAndLossById(user);
        System.out.println("iside currentProfitPercPA" + currentProfitPercPA);
        return currentProfitPercPA;
    }
/**
     * Returns currentProfitPercPA.
     * @return
     */
}
```

Comment: how does homePageServiceFactory.getObject() work? can you add that here

Comment: There are lots of reasons why this might not work. Opaquely reaching out into a static global context is a Bad Thing, and this is why. Supply the user as a parameter. Spring makes it easy to do that automatically with `@AuthenticationPrincipal`.

Comment: @chrylis : can you specify in which way you are telling to pass. But It works when i pass parameter as user.getId()

Comment: how do i can pass the user object ?? Is there any way to pass ??